# Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str when trying to read data from dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

In below program, I have  "data" which contains a dictionary and list. I am trying to read the value of "role" but getting the error:

```
import json

data = {"users":[{"user_id":"11w","device_id":"AQ","role":"OWN","links":{"rel":"self","href":"test_link"}}]}

k= json.loads(data)
role= k["users"]["role"]
print role
```

**Error** : TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You have a dictionary which contains a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary which contains a dictionary. Try `k["users"][0]["role"]`.

Comment: @Graipher I think that your comment count as an answer

Comment: @Gsk: I added this (slightly expanded) as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dictionary which contains a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary which contains a dictionary. And lists can only be indexed with integers (and slices, but they also contain integers).

To get the role of the first (and only one in this example) user, just use this:

```
role = k["users"][0]["role"]
print role
# OWN
```

Or, if you have multiple users, iterate over them:

```
for user in k["users"]:
    print user["role"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line by line:

```
data = {"users":[{"user_id":"11w","device_id":"AQ","role":"OWN","links":{"rel":"self","href":"test_link"}}]}
```

`data` now holds a dictionary of a list of a dictionary.

```
k = json.loads(data)
```

Gives a json TypeError as json.loads needs to be passed a string, not a python data structure like `data`.

```
role = k["users"]["role"]
```

As you have discovered this doesn't work. Let's find the data step by step:

```
print(data["users"])
[{'user_id': '11w', 'device_id': 'AQ', 'role': 'OWN', 'links': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'test_link'}}]
```

Note that this is a list ("[...]") not a dictionary. To access this list members you use integers, not strings. So next step extract the first (and only) member of this list:

```
print(data["users"][0])
{'user_id': '11w', 'device_id': 'AQ', 'role': 'OWN', 'links': {'rel': 'self', 'href': 'test_link'}}
```

Now we have the nested dictionary which we can lookup by key string:

```
print(data["users"][0]["role"])
'OWN'
```

Finally we have the answer you are looking for.